# Java Button drag and drop or hard coding in NetBeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am a beginner to Java UI designing and development. What is the best way to work with `JButton`? manually (by coding) or in design view (drag and drop)

If I add java buttons manually, Is it possible to position using the design view?

Comment: if you want to have insight how swing works you should do it manually, after that you can have drag and drop.

Comment: @jackjay, if I drag and drop the buttons, will it generate the code as I manually type it ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the 'hard' in *"..hard coding.."*?

Comment: ..as in, DYM that using layouts is 'hard', or that the exact positions of components are being set in pixels (AKA 'hard coded')?

Comment: @Senura yes it generates the code for you but that wont help much if you are going to open that without IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a beginner like me and you, it is always good to code manually. You will have knowledge of proper positioning the components and different layouts. After you get it, move to drag and drop for rapid development.

Comment: as you have said .. just think I know how to code manually. then i will move on to drag and drop method. So will the drag and drop method creates the codes for the buttons as we type (will the code-behind is visible and is it same as we hard code the jbuttons)?

Comment: @Senura Form editors tend to "automate" the process, generally speaking though, they do tend to make messy code and generally the code can't be shared with other people not using the same IDE, which is one of the many reasons we recommend hand coding. I find form editors are good for quick planning of a idea, but unless your careful, can produce a really be (code) design - IMHO

Comment: @Senura Yeah, drag and drop will create the code behind the scene. For example, if you choose a JButton and place it in the JPanel then the code is automatically written. You can see the code too.